# Can I add a thermostat C wire to my furnace's control board if there's already a wire under the screw?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I bought a new WiFi thermostat and it requires 5 wires and I only have 4 currently.

I will run a new set of wires from the thermostat to board, however on the board it shows that I have a C wire but that wire does not go to thermostat, I believe it goes to unit outside as that wire is attached to another set of 2 thin cables and it does not to go thermostat.

My question is: when I run the new set of wires, can I just attach the C cable into that splice?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. While you're waiting for a response, please take the [tour] so you can learn how to get the most out this Q&A forum